# How to find pair of reflected point of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, inverse-function

$f(x)=4+\sqrt{x-2}\\f^{-1}(x)=x^2-8x+18\\g(x)=x$

Obtain the graph of  $f$ , $f^{-1}(x)$, and  $g(x)=x$  in the same system of axes.

About what pair (a, a) are (11, 7) and (7, 11) reflected about?

---

After I graphed three equations, there is no pair point met at (11,7) and (7,11).

What does this question mean?

```
About what pair (a, a) are (11, 7) and (7, 11) reflected about?
```

Comment: If you regard the two points as the endpoints of a line segment, then the point $(a,a)$ is the midpoint of that line segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inverse of $f$ is correct, so graphing all three functions should yield the following:

[image]

Where by setting all three functions equal to each other and solving for $x$ we get the intersection of the functions at the point $(6,6)$ (a point of the form $(a,a)$ (where $a$ is a real number)). However, this is not the pair on the line $g(x) = x$ where $(11,7)$ and $(7,11)$ are reflected about. Points of the form $(a,b), (b,a)$ (where $b$ is a real number) are reflected about the midpoint between the two points.

So, in this case the midpoint between $(11,7)$ and $(7,11)$ is $(9,9)$, i.e. the point of reflection shown in the (piece of the) graph below. Keep in mind: $f(11) = 7$ and $f^{-1}(7) = 11$

[image]

Comment: Please don't hesitate to ask any questions!

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your answer.

Comment: Of course! Happy to help.